# How to format a textfield so when user inputs data its in format similar to 80/150?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Currently there is a textfield that after a user enters data it has to post to a server in a format similar to 60/500, so basically a fraction.  I'm familiar with setting up a textfield and connecting it via storyboard along with setting up text input traits so the number pad will show up.  I'm just not sure how to change the entered textfield into the '30/90' fraction format and posting it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean 2 digits + slash + 3 or three digits ?

Comment: @Carpsen90 2 digits + slash + three digits

Comment: You need to update your question and clarify how you actually want this to work. Show clear examples of how the text field should be formatted as the user types into the text field. How to handle a user pasting stuff into the text field. What should happen if the user moves the caret or selects some of the text and inserts or deletes, etc. And please show what you have tried. There are many, many examples of formatting text entered into a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way, after setting `self` as the delegate:

```
let slash = "/"
let digits = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    //Deleting
    if string.count == 0 {
        var text = textField.text!
        let start = text.startIndex
        let beginRange = text.index(start, offsetBy: range.location)
        let endRange = text.index(start, offsetBy: range.location + range.length)
        text = String(text.prefix(upTo: beginRange))
            + String(text.suffix(from: endRange))
        text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "")
        if text.count >= 3 {
            text = String(text.prefix(2)) + "/" + String(text.dropFirst(2))
        }

        textField.text = text

        return false
    }

    //Typing

    let count = textField.text!.count
    guard string.count == 1,
        count < 6,
        let scalar = Character(string).unicodeScalars.first else {
            return false
    }

    let isDigit = digits.contains(scalar)

    switch count {
    case 0, 3..<6 :
        return isDigit
    case 1:
        if isDigit {
            textField.text = textField.text! + string + "/"
        }
        return false
    case 2:
        if string == slash {
            return true
        } else {
            textField.text = textField.text! + "/" + string
            return false
        }
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

This code works with the default keyboard too, and not just the numeric pad.